# Does multiple query block on single connection(SqlConnection)?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a sample Data Access method design below which calls recursively:

```
public static void DeleteRecord(SqlConnection connection, string childIds, string parentSheetname)
{
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("...", connection))
    {
        //fill a datatable
        string newIds = "...";
        string newParentName = "...";

        const string query = "DELETE FROM table " + 
                             "WHERE ids in (@ids) AND parent = @parent";
        //Here's where recursion takes place
        DeleteRecord(connection, newIds, newParentName);

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            var parameters = new[] { 
                new SqlParameter(...), new SqlParameter(...)
            }
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }



}
```

**My questions are:**

1. (As a good practice) Is it okay to pass the connection as a parameter?
2. Is it okay to put the `DeleteRecord` method on a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) so each time I call it, there's no waiting time for the command to execute the query. (of course there's a `Task.WaitAll(tasks)` somewhere)
3. On the scenario number 2, do the connection will block the multiple queries sent over server? I've experienced SQLServer is suspending some queries if it has heavy query executing. (Connection pooling is enabled by default, so I'm wondering if this  also a case here on item 3)

Comment: You should use connection on demand - open it before action and free/close when it's necessary. You shouldn't keep connection open when it's not being used.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, what do you mean `when it's not being used`? On my code above, the `connection` object is always used. It would take 2 - 4 seconds for each recursive calls.

Comment: You shouldn't attempt any sharing of connection objects - you should, ideally, for each command object create a new connection object, open it, execute your command (and process any result sets) and close it again. Behind the scenes, .NET will minimize the number of *actual* network connections (look up connection pooling for more info)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, your comment constrasts Joel Coehoorn answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644849/open-sqlconnection-being-passed-as-a-parameter#12644896).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot execute multiple statements concurrently on a connection. If you want to execute multiple statements you need to use multiple connections. However, in your case that would be a bad idea. You need to wrap your deletion in a transaction to maintain database consistency. Deleting the items on separate connections cannot achieve transactional consistency.

You should think in sets, not items. Pass all the items to be deleted at once. See [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) for details how to achieve this. Use a single DELETE statement that joins the entire parameter set.

Comment: I'll re-design it on `think in sets` method, and use `where = 1` to create dynamic filters. Before you answer here, I've been thinking if I'm going to use your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544905/beginexecutenonquery-without-endexecutenonquery#1544978) on using `command.BeginExecuteNonQuery()`.

Answer (score 0):

**(Replying as a answer as i am not getting add comment option)**
-@MarcinJuraszek:+5 to him.
Default pool size is 100(max).So it will suspend the subsequent requests more than this. To overcome this its good practice to close each open connection wherever necessary.

-when it's not being used? simply means close the connection at the end of your code.It doesnt matter how much your code takes to execute,it will just close the connection when it reaches the specified code connection.close();

Comment: Is passing `connection` a bad idea?

Comment: No its ok.But do not concatenate strings to build a SQL command. It leaves you wide open to accidental or deliberate SQL Injection attack which can destroy your entire database. Use Parametrized queries instead. like                                              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select uname, pswd from emp_details where uname = (at)id and pswd = (at)password ", conn); after this statement add :                                                       cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("(at)id", "id here"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("(at)password", "password here"));

Comment: Have you seen this on my question? `var parameters = new[] {  SqlParameter(...), new SqlParameter(...)}`